# Misplaced Scroll Bar When scrollTo Called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the below function to scroll to a Div inside a Div.

It works but the car stays at last position so if the user scrolls it flashes to the original position. To clarify the scroll bar is actually at the top of the div but the user sees to bottom element but when user scrolls up he or she doesn't get the expected result of moving to the element right above the last they get bumped to the top.

```
 jQuery.fn.scrollTo = function (elem, speed) {
            $(this).animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top + $(elem).offset().top
            }, speed == undefined ? 1000 : speed);
            return this;
        };

onclick="$('#usermessageDiv').scrollTo('.last_usermessage', 2000);"

 $('.small-chat-box .content').slimScroll({
            height: '234px',
            railOpacity: 0.4
        });
  <div id="usermessageDiv" class="content" style="overflow: scroll; width: auto; height: 234px;">
```

The image below shows where the bar is vs the 2nd lower red arrow where the scroll bar should be in regards to the view shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SlimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) has a `scrollTo` setting that you should use instead of your scrollTo function.

> scrollTo - Jumps to the specified scroll value. Can be called on any
>   element with slimScroll already enabled. Example:
>   `$(element).slimScroll({ scrollTo: '50px' });`

You will need to use jQuery's [`position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) method to get the scroll distance of the target element relative to the parent. If you need detailed help with that, please post some HTML for the `usermessageDiv`.

Comment: Tried $(ele).scrollTop(position) with same result but I'll try other as well